# Invalidate-like method for WallpaperServices' draw method

Tags: android, canvas, invalidation

I was trying to make moving bitmap with accelerometer smoother and accidentally noticed that when I call `invalidate();` at the end of `onDraw()` method instead of calling it at the end of `onSensorChanged()` I get much smoother movement, even if I don't have any kind of low-pass filters. Then I tried to do the same with my LiveWallpaper, but as you know there is no `onDraw()` method in `Engine` of `WallpaperService`, but you have to create one yourself and call it for example with `Handler`. But doing it that way doesn't give any smoother result even if the rest of the code is same as in other programs.

This is the code that I use in my non-Wallpaper programs and it works fine:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas c) {

xPosition += xAcceleration;
yPosition += yAcceleration;

drawable = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ball);
c.drawBitmap(drawable, xPosition,yPosition, paint);

invalidate();

}
```

So I went and tried to create my own invalidate-like solution for `WallpaperService` and came up with this:

```
void drawFrame() {
final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();

Canvas c = null;
try {
c = holder.lockCanvas();
if (c != null) {
xPosition += xAcceleration;
yPosition += yAcceleration;

background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.bg);
drawable = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ball);

c.drawBitmap(background, 0,0, null);
c.drawBitmap(drawable, xPosition,yPosition, null);
}
} catch (Exception ex){
}
holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
drawFrame();
}
```

So what I am doing is:

1. Get `Canvas`.
2. Draw on `Canvas`.
3. Unlock `Canvas` and start over.

As I have understood this should give me `invalidate();`-like behaviour, but instead it tries to show wallpaper and after while it gives me StackOverflowError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got this solved already. All I had to to was move bitmap initializations into `onCreate()` method.

Comment: I was going to say that by invalidating in the draw (if not FPS locked) it would draw as fast as the code or device would allow.  By invalidating on the sensor, it would redraw on sensor update.  IE.  It might update at 60fps on the draw, but the sensor might only update 45fps.

Comment: Oh btw, you are right too.  You were probably leaking memory as you were decoding the same bitmaps over and over in the loop.